# Is it OK to call Service.startService() from within Service.onBind()?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service which I want to make sure does NOT stop() when there are no longer any activities bound to it.

I understand that startService() is used to achieve this, but is it okay to call this from within the service's onBind() method?

Calling it from the activity seems like a hack to me, because the service know's best whether it wants to hang around after onUnbind().

The activities indicate the current state of the service and provide some control, so bindService() seems like the appropriate method to use here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be fine to call `startService()` from within `onBind()`. If you have logic in `onBind()` that can determine that the service needs to stay up even if the client has unbound then that seems to be the logical place to do it.

I disagree with the answer that claims it is not recommended. The architecture you've described is making effective use of encapsulation. Clients only want to bind/unbind and they shouldn't have to know how the service is (internally) implemented. The service should control its own lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `startService()` from `onBind()` is not recommended. `onBind()` is meant for connecting to clients, you should not change the behavior.

Before a client wants to connect, let it call `startService()`, if service is already running, it will have no effect, client object can then bind. service will still be running when clients unbind. If service knows when not to be around it can safely call `stopSelf()` on itself and exit.

Comment: Definitely this service should not start at boot.  stopSelf() is only useful if startService() has been called, right?  The question is, where to call startService() from, if not from onBind()?

Comment: @MarkCarter you can call it from whichever client wants to connect, calling it again has no effect if it has been called once.

Comment: The client does not know that the service wants to hang around after all the clients have unbound, so it seems to me like the wrong place to call startService.  It will work, but, for me, it's a design smell. The question is not so much "Where can startService be called from?" but rather specifically about the pros/cons of calling it from onBind().